# Python: How to print a value that is returned

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a program that solves a physics question, and I am stuck.
My question is, how can I print a value that is returned?
For example:
(suppose u is the input, which is a list)

```
def solver(u):
    if (u[6]*g*sin(u[0])) > (u[6]*g*cos(u[0])*u[3]):
        x1total = (1.0/2.0)*g*sin(u[0])*u[9]*u[9] 
        return x1total

    else:
        x1total=0
        return x1total

    if (u[7]*g*sin(u[1])) > (u[7]*g*cos(u[1])*u[3]):
        x2total = (1.0/2.0)*g*sin(u[0])*u[9]*u[9] 
        return x2total

    else:
        x2total = 0
        return x2total

    print [x1total,x2total]

solver(u)
```

Now, what I expect is to get the outputs as a list. However, I get nothing. Help me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function never makes it to the `print` statement because all possible cases hit a `return`.

Remove all of the `return` statements and it should print ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your `print` statement is after the `return` statement.

The `return` statement causes the execution of the function to be stopped. The value specified in the statement is returned to the caller.

To get the returned value, you do this:

```
value = solver(u)
```

Then you can:

```
print value
```